# Redux-saga runs in a inifinite loop

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Redux saga runs in infinite loop even after the PROJECTS_SUCCEDED is triggered again it runs back to the fetchData method. please find the saga code below

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { put, all, take, call, takeLatest , takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import actions from './actions';

const getRequest =  () =>{
    const data =  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
                    .then( res => res.json())
                    .catch(err => {throw err});
    return data;
}

 function* fetchData(action) {
    console.log('fetchdata');
    try{
        const data = yield call(getRequest);
        console.log(data)
        yield put({type:actions.PROJECTS_SUCCEDED, payload:data});
    }
    catch (err){
        yield put({type:actions.PROJECTS_FAILED,err:err});
    }
}

function* dashboardSaga(){
    console.log('saga ran once')
    yield  takeLatest(actions.projectsRequested, fetchData);        
}

export default dashboardSaga;
```

and the action is invoked in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.projectsRequested();
    }
```

and the root saga is

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import homeSaga from './dashboard/sagas';

export default function* rootSaga(getState) {
    yield all([
        homeSaga(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve the above issue by changing the lifecycle method to componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated.  Avoid using it if possible. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Answer (score 0):

Here you need use action type for requesting

`function* dashboardSaga(){
    console.log('saga ran once')
    yield  takeLatest(actions.PROJECTS_REQUESTING, fetchData);
}`